# In MongoDB - trying to perform a recursive lookup between 2 collections where 1 collection has a nested relationship within that collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The scenario is I have 2 collections - 1 with a list of users and 1 with a list of groups.

```
"users": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "username": "Fred Smith",
      "level": 12,
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "username": "Bob Brown",
      "level": 20,
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "username": "Joe Blogs",
      "level": 1
    }
  ],
```

A group holds a list of users but crucially also potentially holds groups within the same list as well.

```
"groups": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "groupname": "admin",
      "members": ["Fred Smith"]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "groupname": "users",
      "members": [
        "Fred Smith",
        "Bob Brown",
        "contractors"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "groupname": "contractors",
      "members": ["Joe Blogs"]
    },
   {
      "_id": 4,
      "groupname": "all",
      "members": ["users"]
    }]
```

Given a query of a specific username I need to return all groups that user is a member of.

So far I have the $graphLookup working in the following playground - but I am not sure of the next step to take into account the nested group name inside that list of users.  There is also the possibility the groups may nested further groups.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "username": "Joe Blogs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "groups",
      "startWith": "$username",
      "connectFromField": "username",
      "connectToField": "members",
      "as": "groups",
      "maxDepth": 10
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "username": 1,
      "groups": "$groups.groupname"
    }
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/GBRJp42bdjt

```
[
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "groups": [
      "contractors"
    ],
    "username": "Joe Blogs"
  }
]
```

In this example I have queried Fred who is a member of the **contractors** group but the **contractors** group is also a member of the **users** group and the **users** group is a member of the **all** group.

So I would need the query to return both **contractors** (which it does now) but also **users** and **all**.

It feels like given an initial array of groups in this query I then need to do a different query with the array of groups to find out what groups they are a member of.

I could modify the structure if required to make this easier but the nesting of groups is a requirement.

Any help appreciated.

As an update I have created another query which given an array of groups will return a normalised list of all the nested groups - https://mongoplayground.net/p/9NGG_wIJkGX

Now I just need to work out how to feed the results of the first query to the second query - if anyone has an idea I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first playground is actually very close already. You just need to use `groupname` in `connectFromField` in the `$graphLookup` to traverse the collection. At the last `$project` stage, use `$reduce` with `$setUnion` to extract all the groups from the `$graphLookup` result.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "username": "Joe Blogs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "groups",
      "startWith": "$username",
      "connectFromField": "groupname",
      "connectToField": "members",
      "as": "groups",
      "maxDepth": 10
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "username": 1,
      "groups": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$groups",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$setUnion": [
              "$$value",
              [
                "$$this.groupname"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/waxoCx-Mqzp)

Comment: That's great thanks Ray - I need to go away and learn what that reduce function is actually doing - it's a shame there is no debugger for Aggregations!

Comment: @markbarton Here is the [official doc of `$reduce`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/). You can think of it as iterating an array, processing the array entries one by one and "combine" the result with an accumulator (i.e. `$$value`). In our scenario, it is used for flattening an array of arrays to get the values in `groups.groupname`